# WiX major upgrade doesn't copy any new file in the MSI package in the budle

Tags: wix, major-upgrade

I have an earlier version of our product (v 3.01.x.y) installed. When installing the new version (3.31.x.y) which is a bundle with a few packages inside, it installs successfully with no errors in the log and the Add or Remove Programs shows the new version as well as the PackageCache has the msi sitting there, however, the new files from the main package StudioInstallerMSI are not copied to the target folder on the destination, the folder is missing at all. Below is the budle.wxs file content:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">

  <?include $(var.SolutionDir)\StudioInstaller\StudioInstaller\Variables.wxi?>

  <Bundle Name="$(var.SciFullProductName)"
          Version="!(bind.packageVersion.StudioInstallerMSI)"
          Manufacturer="!(bind.packageManufacturer.StudioInstallerMSI)"
          UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)"
          IconSourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)\..\StudioInstaller\Resources\STUDIO.ICO">

    <WixVariable Id="PrerequisitesDirectory" Value="Prerequisites\" />

    <Variable Name="BA_SciProductName" Value="$(var.SciProductName)" />

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile=".\Resources\EULA.rtf"
                                              LogoFile=".\Resources\Banner.jpg"
                                              ThemeFile="$(var.SolutionDir)\SciWixLibrary\SciBaseTheme.xml"
                                              LocalizationFile="$(var.SolutionDir)\SciWixLibrary\SciBaseTheme.wxl" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx48Redist" />
      <PackageGroupRef Id="VCRedist_x64" />
      <PackageGroupRef Id="SqlLocalDB_x64" />
      <PackageGroupRef Id="FLMInstallerMSI" />
      <MsiPackage Id="StudioInstallerMSI" SourceFile="$(var.StudioInstaller.TargetPath)" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes">
        <MsiProperty Name="BUNDLE_UI_LEVEL" Value="[WixBundleUILevel]" />
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

And the content of the main wxs file of the main package StudioInstallerMSI is below:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <?include $(sys.CURRENTDIR)\Variables.wxi?>
  <?include $(sys.CURRENTDIR)\..\..\SciWixLibrary\SharedVariables.wxi?>
  
  <Product Id="*" Name="$(var.SciProductName)" Language="1033" Codepage='1252' Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">

    <Package Id='*' Keywords='Installer' Description="$(var.SciProductName) v. $(var.ProductVersion) Installer"
             Comments='$(var.SciProductName) is a registered trademark of $(var.Manufacturer)' Manufacturer='$(var.Manufacturer)'
             InstallerVersion='500' Languages='1033' Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" AllowDowngrades="no" DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." Disallow="no" Schedule="afterInstallInitialize" />

    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <!-- The upgrade code of the old legacy product used in the InstallShield based installers -->
    <Upgrade Id="9BEACA3B-D4F4-45E6-A288-509C608CF1A6">
      <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect='no' Property='OLD_IS_PRODUCTCODE' Maximum='3.0.0.0' IncludeMaximum='no' IgnoreRemoveFailure='no' />
    </Upgrade>

     <Feature Id="StudioComponents" Title="Sciemetric Studio Components" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="HarvestedSTComponents" />
      <ComponentRef Id="cmpRemoveSTUnversionedFiles" />
    </Feature>
   </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="SystemFolder" />
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
        <Directory Id="SciemetricDIR" Name="Sciemetric">
          <Directory Id="SciStudioDIR" Name="Sciemetric Studio" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The same outcome is for the other secondary package FLMInstallerMSI, which also gets upgraded to the latest version in the Add or Remove Programs, however, in this case the previous version files stay the same and not replaced with the new version files from that package.

Could you please help understand what am I missing here? If I uninstall the previous version and install the new version everything is installed successfully and no file is missing. Only the major upgrade that causes this issue.

Additional observation info: the bundle is OK, since I installed the previous version and then installed only the main MSI package StudioInstallerMSI, which uninstalls the previous version, I can see how it creates the destination folder and copies the new files, but then in a split second after it deletes the target folder again. Hope this helps.

Comment: Look at the verbose log file for the MSI package. That will tell you a lot.

Comment: @RobMensching I generated the verbose log, but it doesn't show any sign of error or reason why would the files get removed at the end. I can see the previous components being unregistered and files deleted, then I can see the new components being registered and files being copied over to the destination. Then all that being followed by "InstallFinalize. Return value 1.". Later the log states "Product: Studio -- Installation completed successfully.". I don't see how the copied new files are being deleted. I can see the folder being created and then deleted in a split second.

Comment: @RobMensching I can share the verbose log in the WiX Users group mail if that can be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it takes that level of analysis, it's gone beyond what I do for fun on StackOverflow. Consider a support contract from FireGiant (https://www.firegiant.com/) if you need expert help.